# More concise alternative to JavaScript conditional ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

There are many cases where using a `conditional ternary operator` allows for preferring `const` over `let`:

```js
let scaleFactor = 1;
if (prev.scale < 1 && current.scale < 1) {
  scaleFactor = 5;
}
```

With ternary and const:

```js
const scaleFactor =
  prev.scale < 1 && current.scale < 1 ? 5 : 1;
```

I see and use this pattern a lot. Is there a more concise way to write this that I've been missing?

**Update:** 
An example of alternative to ternary that is both shorter and more readable

```
const t =  tX > 0
               ? 0
               : tX < width - width * scale
               ? width - width * scale
               : tX
```

```
const t = Math.max(Math.min(tX, 0), width - width * scale)
```

Comment: Programs are not written to be short, they're written to be read by humans. Your code should be clear and understandable, not as short as possible.

Comment: Agree with @Nit, whatever transpiler you use will crunch it down to save space, but readability should be high in the source.

Comment: To answer your question, no, this is the shortest way to short circuit an `if-else` statement

Comment: @Nit there's a difference between conciseness and shortness. Take a look at switch expressions in Scala / Kotlin / C#, they are both shorter and more readable and don't require you to create mutable variable only to assign it in the next statement

Comment: Less than 2 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Although I completely agree with some of the people commenting on your question that short != concise, I do think your question is valid. For many cases where you have the pattern if set value to X else to Y, you can do an expression that involves the boolean conditions as factors. Some options:

```
if (C)
   value = X
else
   value = Y
```

can be converted to

```
value = C * X + !C * Y;
```

Same thing can be written as:

```
value = X + !C * (Y - X)
```

I am a game developer, and it's quite often that I need something like:

```
// 1 if the right arrow was pressed, -1 for the left, 0 otherwise
var changeInMovementX = hasRightArrowBeenPressed - hasLeftArrowBeenPressed;
// same for up and down
var changeInMovementY = hasTopArrowBeenPressed - hasDownArrowBeenPressed;
// move 1 pixel in the given directions
player.move(changeInMovementX, changeInMovementX);
```

For your specific example, you might consider something like:

```
const shouldIncreaseScale = prev.scale < 1 && current.scale < 1;
const scaleIncrease = 4;
const scaleFactor = 1 + shouldIncreaseScale * scaleIncrease;
```

Comment: Characters count is always going to be a dodgy metric for code quality. While you haven't made it shorter, I think you have expressed the _intent_ better and to me that's what matters the most. Perhaps the only "criticism" I would make is that it implies that the reader is familiar with type coercion rules. e.g. `false` is converted into `0` when it is involved in numbers operations. Overall I think this is very good indeed.

Answer (score -2):

In short, language feature like switch expression doesn't yet exist in Javascript. But there are a few things you can do depending on your liking

1. IIFE with switch statement that returns

```
const a = 5
const c1 = (() => {
  switch (a) {
    case 1: {
      return 2
    }
    case 2: {
      return 3
    }
    default: {
      return 4
    }
  }
})()

console.log(c1)
```

2. IIFE with if statement

```
const c2 = (() => {
  if (a === 1) {
    return 2
  } else if (a < 10 && b > 10) {
    return 3
  } else {
    return 4
  }
})()

console.log(c2)
```

3. custom helper

```
// define this once
const conditionalHelper = (cases, defaultValue) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
    const [predicate, value] = cases[i]
    if (predicate()) {
      return value
    }
  }
  return defaultValue
}

const c3 = conditionalHelper(
  [
    [() => a === 1, 2],
    [() => a < 10 && b > 10, 3],
  ],
  4
)
console.log(c3)
```